# How do I write my own ListSelectionEvent?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listselectionlistener

I made a GUI that holds a list. When a selection is made in that list, via the user clicking the list selection, some action is performed. I want to be able to test that action without having to actually make a selection through the GUI. 
For example I have my GUI.java and a separate GUITest.java. Id like to do something like[image: GUITest.java]

valueChanged() is a method from the java interface ListSelectionListener and only accepts parameters of type ListSelectionEvent. So ultimately, how would I create my own ListSelectionEvent variable that holds the action that "a" was selected?

Comment: `ListSelectionEvent` is a complicated class, start by looking at the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html).  It takes 4 parameters, the `source`, which will be your `JList`, the `firstIndex` and `lastIndex`, these can be the same for the value you want to select and `isAdjusting`, which probably should be `false`, but indicates if there are more events in the sequence to come

Comment: So, the long and short would be `new ListSelectionEvent(list, 0, 0, false)` :/

Comment: You should be able to create an instance of the Event and then simply call the appropriate method defined in the ListListener interface.  Make certain you call it from the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought of this which performs the same task much easier I think. The method valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) automatically runs when a selection in the list is made. With this in mind, I will be able test the action of "a" being selected, using the method setSelectedIndex(index). valueChanged(...) will detect the change made from the call: list.setSelectedIndex(...)

```
public class GUI implements ListSelectionListener{
    String[] letters = {"a", "b", "c"};
    JList list = new JList(letters);
    list.addListSelectionListener(this);

    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
        if(list.getSelectedValue().equals("a")){
            System.out.println("Success");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Fail");
        }
    }
}
```

then from my test class

```
public class GUITest{
    @test
    void testListSelection(){
        GUI t = new GUI();
        t.list.setSelectedIndex(0);
        assert(whatever test your doing);
    }
}
```

The if statement for "a" as selected value was covered during a JUnit test.